# can't redirect to a page named meet in NextJS 13 (router.push not working as intended)

Tags: typescript, next.js13

```
import { Input, Button } from '@nextui-org/react';
import router from 'next/router';
import { SetStateAction,  useEffect,  useState } from 'react';

const SignIn = () => {
  
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  const handleEmailChange = (e: { target: { value: SetStateAction<string>; }; }) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e: { target: { value: SetStateAction<string>; }; }) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
   const handleSignIn = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });
      console.log('response:',response)
      if (response.ok) {

        // Redirect to the dashboard or any other page on successful login
        console.log('response2:',response)
        router.push('/meet');
      } else {
        // Handle authentication error (display error message, etc.)
        setErrorMessage('Login failed.');
        console.error('Authentication failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle fetch error
      console.error('Error occurred while signing in:', error);
    }
};
```

I cant redirect to a page called meet. The page meet is the same directory. (router.push not working clearly).

Is router.push deprecated or is there a mistake in the code? What am I doing wrong here?.The api works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can using try the following below code

```html
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
---------------
const router = useRouter()
--------------
router.push('/post');
```

You can see: [Building a simple CRUD API with NextJS 13](https://hoanguyenit.com/building-a-simple-crud-api-with-nextjs-13.html)